# how to plot a bidirectional flip bargraph with count data?

Tags: r, plot

I am analysing some data with a binomial distribution.
We have 2 possible choices for a stimulus, and patients (female and male) have to decide whether they feel pain (1) or not (0).

I would like to plot a bargraph showing the number of patients who choose 0 or 1, in a rotated way.

An idea of the graph I am looking for is the following, from Sevarika et al, 2022. [image]

```
#my data
id<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10)
trt<-c("C","E","C","E","C","E","C","E","C","E","C","E","C","E","C","E","C","E","E","C")
response<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
sex<-c(rep("male",5),rep("female",5))
data<-data.frame(id,trt,response,sex)
```

So my objective is a flipped boxplot where females and males are separated, and the number of 1 or 0 is shown on each side of the axis. I mean, where it says control, let it say 0, where it says treatment let it say 1, and the top bar should be males and the bottom bar should be females.

Thank you very much, best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R way:

```r
# compute percentages
tab <- t(table(data$response, data$sex) * c(-1, 1))
tab <- tab / rowSums(abs(tab)) * 100

# positions of x axis labels
lab.x <- seq(-100, 100, 25)
# initiate new plot
frame()
par(mar=c(2.5, 1, 2, 1))
plot.window(range(lab.x), c(0, 1))
# draw x axis
axis(1, at=lab.x, labels=abs(lab.x))
# draw vertical lines
abline(v=0)
abline(v=c(-1, 1)*50, lty=2)
# bar middle y coordinates
bar.mid <- c(.3, .7)
# bar height
bar.ht <- .25
# draw bars
rect(c(tab), bar.mid - bar.ht/2, 0, bar.mid + bar.ht/2,
     col=rep(gray(c(.8, .2)), each=2))
mtext(c('No pain', 'Pain'), 3, at=c(-1, 1)*40, cex=1.3, line=.5)
# print bar labels (male, female)
text(min(lab.x), bar.mid, rownames(tab), adj=0)
```

[image: Horizontal barplots]

Comment: perfect, just what I was looking for
Just one more thing, would it be possible to move the position of the text "male" and "female"?

Thank you very much

Comment: @Miquel Sure, if you mean to the left or to the right then just change `min(lab.x)` in the last line to e.g. -120 to move it more to the left or -80 to move it to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wrangle your data into a more appropriate format for plotting. Here's one method of doing it:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  count(response, sex) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(response == 0, -n, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sex, n, fill = factor(response))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-3, 3), linetype = 2, size = 0.2) +
  geom_col(position = 'identity', color = 'black', width = 0.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-7, 7), name = 'count', limits = c(-7, 7)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#bebebe", "#2a2a2a"), guide = 'none') +
  annotate('text', y = c(-4, 4), x = c(2.8, 2.8), vjust = 1, size = 6,
           label = c('RESPONSE = 0', 'RESPONSE = 1'), fontface = 2) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 1), name = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]